# AWS Lambda doesn't terminate function instance after calling

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have AWS lambda function for downloading from S3, creating zip archive and uploading back to S3.
Sometimes I see in the logs that my function called twice. I will try to describe in details. My lambda function wait some parameters:

```
 "OutputBucket": 'bucketName',
 "OutputKey": 'Zip/result.zip', * just for example
 "SourceBucket": 'bucketName',
 "SourcePrefix": 'projects/1990/6068/' *this is path to folder in S3
```

When user clicks button I call lambda function:

```
_lambdaClient.Invoke(invokeRequest);
```

I see in the debugger, all data filled correctly and this code called once.

But in the logs I see that lambda called twice and with different parameters. It's happen when I click button, then wait until it will have finished then click again for another project.

This is the screenshot of logs:
[image]

As you can see there two START/END records. Also interval between them 4 minutes.
In result I have zip file which contains files from two different projects.

Where is a problem?

Comment: "It's happen when I click button, then wait until it will have finished then click again for another project" So you are clicking the button twice, and seeing the Lambda function called twice. Isn't this exactly what you would expect? This looks like it is working exactly as intended. Please state what your expected behavior is.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, But I clicked later. After several minutes.  Therefore, My second execution contains files from first execution. It's wrong, in this situation second user can get files from first user. This is important security issue.

Comment: Each execution does not get a new environment. They are reused. You need to delete any files at the end of the function to prevent your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> "After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda maintains the
>   container for some time in anticipation of another Lambda function
>   invocation. In effect, the service freezes the container after a
>   Lambda function completes, and thaws the container for reuse, if AWS
>   Lambda chooses to reuse the container when the Lambda function is
>   invoked again."

It will definitely attempt to reuse your previous function for a period of time.  For those of us that use Lambda instantiated Kestrel servers, it helps prevent setup code duplication for every call made.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html